# How can another column's value includes value of primary key in spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

[image]

I will pass className in the request, in the entity I would to store the class Name field as like above.

Primary key value should be appended with my class name. How we do it.

I have an approach, 
1. Insert the record first
2. Update the same record with primary key value.

I hope it is an bad approach, is it possible to do in the single save call? If not, what will be the efficient work around to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already suspect this is not a good idea. But anyway, I highly recommend that you don't actually store the data that way, only display it that way. You can do this with `@PostLoad` callback. Add an event listener to your entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(FooListener.class)
public class Foo {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long primaryId;

  private String className;
  ...
  ...
}
```

And implement Post Load:

```
public class FooListener {
    @PostLoad
    public void updateClassName( Foo p ) {
        p.setClassName(p.getClassName() + "_" + p.getPrimaryId());
    }
}
```